# MySQL 8 window functions syntax problems

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to use window functions in MySQL. I'm using MySQL Server 8.0.11, and even the MySQL Workbench 8.0.11 (Development Release, not GA).

This should make Workbench available to read window functions. Before, they just worked, but I need them to be readable by Workbench in order to store them as procedures.

When I do a simple query, I keep getting:

> "SELECT" is no valid input at this position for this server version, expecting: '(', WITH

But if I run the query, it works! It's just that I cannot store this as a procedure. You can see the query and the problem in the screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPr3l.png)

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

EDIT:

I added the screenshot so you could see where the error was appearing. Anyway, this is the code, and the error appears in the first SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM   
     (SELECT * , row_number() over (PARTITION BY VendorID
       ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC) AS RowOrder    
        FROM vendors
     ) t1 
 Where RowOrder = 1 ;
```

Comment: Don't add images just add the code to your question.

Comment: Also, have you tried to execute it? You don't have a server problem this is most likely a problem with your client (workbench). Workbench tends to cache previous typo errors and not update then.

Comment: Jorge. I just did. Sorry this is my first post here. If I execute it, it works! But I need it in a stored procedure, and that's when it won't work unless Syntax is correct, which it is, but not for Workbench 8.0.11. Any idea?

Comment: So, share your procedure code. You probably have defined it in a wrong way. You don't have an error in your query, you have in your procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having troubles with Window functions in MYSQL 8.0.11 as well where they would execute as a workbench query but could not be saved to a SP.

This morning i upgraded both Server and Workbench to 8.0.12 and windows functions now work and I can save to SP. I recommend you give this a go.